# HMTL5 video popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i working on website client demanding when someone comes on video it should autoplay (i did it), when someone click on the video it should open in popup (i did it and working fine). Now he asked me when some click on the video1 and the video in popup should start from the same time as the first video already run like 00:35 sec.
    `

```
this is for video
```

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#video1").click(function(){
          jQuery("#video1 source").clone().prependTo('#video2');
      });
      jQuery("#video1").click(function(){
          jQuery("#video1 source:first-child").remove();
      });
      jQuery("#video2").on("play",function(){
          jQuery("#video1").trigger("pause");
      });
  }); 

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#video1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#vid_overlay').fadeIn('slow');
   });
   jQuery('#vid_overlay').hide();
   jQuery('#video1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#vid_overlay').fadeIn('slow');
   });
   jQuery('#exit_btn').click(function(){
    jQuery('#vid_overlay').fadeOut('slow');
   });

   jQuery('#video1').click(function(){
    this.paused?this.play():this.pause();
   });
   jQuery('#video1').click(function(){
    jQuery("#video2").trigger("play");
   });
   jQuery('#exit_btn').click(function(){
    jQuery("#video2").trigger("pause");
   });
   jQuery('#exit_btn').click(function(){
    jQuery("#video1").trigger("play");
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video1" width="300" controls autoplay loop>
  <source id="video_src" src="videos/BIISummitDubai.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
    and this for is popup
 <div id="vid_overlay">
  <div id="video_wrap">
   <span id="exit_btn">&times;</span>
   <video id="video2" width="800" controls loop>
   </video>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @Stack OverFlow. You have explained your client requirements and your works but forgot to ask the question.

Comment: Why do you repeat so many Events? It's just a bad coding practice.

Comment: yes i know, because i don't have enough experience. could you please help me to solw this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currentTime property sets or returns the current position (in seconds) of the audio/video playback.

When setting this property, the playback will jump to the specified position.

So, you can get the currentTime of the video1 and then set it to video2

Something like this:

```
video2.currentTime = video1.currentTime;
```

Comment: this is the actually problem. could you please guid me how to get current position ?

Comment: const video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
const video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
video2.currentTime = video1.currentTime;

Comment: its not working
const video2 = document.getElementById('video2'); 
  const video1 = document.getElementById('video1'); 
  video2.currentTime = video1.currentTime;

Comment: Yes Sure

`     jQuery("#video1").click(function(){
         jQuery("#video1 source").clone().prependTo('#video2');

   var vid1 = document.getElementById("video1");
   var vid2 = document.getElementById("video2");
      
      vid1.currentTime = vid2.currentTime;

     });
`

Comment: Can you give some more information why it is not working? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No problem. Please set mark my question as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try css only popup so it will play same video in popup with same duration.

```
    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  <a href="#popup1">  <video id="video1" width="300" controls autoplay loop>
        <source id="video_src" src="videos/BIISummitDubai.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
    .overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.overlay:target .popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}


.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  display:none;
}
.overlay:target .popup .close{display:inline-block;}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
```

try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5qce80fs/12/